# ip link set dev up returns RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

Tags: networking, 22.04, can

I have a USB CAN device that create a network interface:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:05:ed:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.156/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 85716sec preferred_lft 85716sec
    inet6 fd4c:5077:bd05:c700:7917:7860:6e2b:7d47/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6854sec preferred_lft 3254sec
    inet6 fd4c:5077:bd05:c700:230:18ff:fe05:ed0d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 6854sec preferred_lft 3254sec
    inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fe05:ed0d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:05:ed:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:84:a5:c1:f1:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can
```

With Ubuntu 21.10 I brought my `can0` interface up with this command:

```
sudo ip link set up can0
```

After upgrading to 22.04 the same command returns:

```
$ sudo ip link set up can0
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Looking at the manual of `ip link` the right syntax is slightly different:

```
ip link set { DEVICE | dev DEVICE | group DEVGROUP }
        [ { up | down } ]
        [ type TYPE ARGS ]
```

So I tried:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev can0 up type can    
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

but the error is the same.
I don't understand the programmers that don't add the details of which is the invalid argument... If I would do something like this I would be fired.

Anyway, what's wrong in my syntax? How to retrieve the offending invalid argument?

Comment: Please try: `sudo ip link set can0 up` Any improvement?

Comment: @chili555 same message

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a type and/or bitrate:

```
sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```